# In Excel, how do you use a list value in a loop to connect the value to a worksheet name?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am attempting to create a loop but running into a slight snag that I cannot seem to figure out how to fix; hoping that someone can help me.

I have a list of names in `Sheet1` `Column A` that I would like to use their values as the Sheet names when the loop is running.

*Example:*

```
Dim Name As String    
Names = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
```

But instead of it sticking with `Range("A1").Value`, I am needing it to swing down the list until it hits a blank row. I found a few different syntax/coding and tried to make it work but got stuck here.

With a list of names in `Column A`, the code will run directly to the bottom of the list, pull the value of the name and go directly to the that sheet.

*Example:*

List in `Column A`:

```
Mark
John
Jason
```

The code will grab `Jason`, go to the `Jason` worksheet, and enter the formula. However, it skips `Mark` and `John`. Not sure how to fix from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub RunTest()

       Dim i, lastcell As Long

       Dim Name As String

       lastcell = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       Name = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value

       Range("A1").Select

    For i = 1 To lastcell

             Sheets(Name).Select

             Range("A1").Select

             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select

             ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=2"

             Sheets("sheet1").Select

             ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't tie `Name` to the current row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for all of that select/activate.

```
Sub RunTest()

    Dim c As Range, wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For Each c In sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), _
                            sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells

        If c.Value <> "" Then
            wb.Sheets(c.Value).Range("C1").Formula = "=2"
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the row:    Range("A1").Select
the row with the Name must be moved directly to the loop.

```
For i = 1 to lastcell
name = cells(i,1)


next i
Name = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value ' - this expression chooses the last name, You can delete it
```